# Unable to add another uiOutput to create equivalent dropdownlist

Tags: r, shiny

I tried to add one more dropdown list for another tab and tied to the same variable  in server.R, but got error msg `'Warning: Error in dval: could not find function "cur_best_option"'`

Original code works fine:

ui.R

```
uiOutput("category")
```

server.R

```
cur_best_option <- reactive({
    return(get_default_option())
})

get_options <- reactive({
    option_list <- some_function()
    option_list
})

output$category <- renderUI({
    option_list <- get_options()
    selectInput("selected_category", "Category", 
                choices=c("", option_list), 
                selected=cur_best_option(), multiple=FALSE)
})

# update the table per dropdown list selection
myTabData <- reactive({
    my_option <- cur_best_option()
    .... # do table update accordingly
})
```

New code got error `'Warning: Error in dval: could not find function "cur_best_option'`:

ui.R

```
uiOutput("category")
...
uiOutput("category2")  # for user to update selected_category/my_option conveniently in another tabView as well
```

server.R

```
cur_best_option <- reactive({
    return(get_default_option())
})

get_options <- reactive({
    option_list <- some_function()
    option_list
})

output$category <- renderUI({
    option_list <- get_options()
    selectInput("selected_category", "Category", 
                choices=c("", option_list), 
                selected=cur_best_option(), multiple=FALSE)
})

# exactly the same content 
output$category2 <- renderUI({
    option_list <- get_options()
    selectInput("selected_category", "Category", 
                choices=c("", option_list), 
                selected=cur_best_option(), multiple=FALSE)
})

# update the table per dropdown list selection
myTabData <- reactive({
    my_option <- cur_best_option()
    .... # do table update accordingly
})
```

The error message complaining about *not findng cur_best_option* makes me confused a lot. I know I probably have some misuse, would appreciate if somebody could give me directions for my use case.

Comment: What is your layout in ui.R file? Does it only have uiOutput("category")
...
uiOutput("category2")?? Can you show code on the layout?

Comment: I tried to use your code and launch the app. I do not get the error, but I see only one dropdown.

Comment: I see two input controls with the same name `selected_category`. That can't really work because you can then only get the results from one of them via `input$selected_category`. It used to even cause Shiny to hang with no message, but now just one of them gets ignored.

Comment: @CrazyKris my ui.R contains some other elements as well, do you have some concerns regarding with layout's influence on my issue?

Comment: Make and CrazyKris, thanks for the info, in my case the UI doesn't display. Trying to figure out other implementations for my use case.

Comment: @PaulLo: Since I am able to see the UI and do not get the error "could not find function "cur_best_option'", its hard to point to the problem without seeing the code.